# How to insert a column with median household income by states to the existing dataframe in R? "Stack overflow Error"

Tags: r, database, dataframe, rscript

I have a downloaded dataframe of American citizens. It has a column "State" providing each observation with the name of some American state.

I need to add median household income by state to the analysis from external source. I'm a freshmen in R so I was doing it manually, like this:

(1) Firstly, I created a vector of mean HH income values

```
hincome <- (c(42.8, 72.2, 48.5, ......... ))
```

(2) I made a cycle that should create a new variable in the data with assigned values of HH median income corresponding with each state.

```
data$hincome <- (ifelse(data$State == "Alabama", 42.8,
            ifelse(data$State == "Alaska", 72.2,
            ifelse(data$State == "Arizona", 48.5,
            ............ ))))
```

Obviously this code has around 56 rows and I get an error:

> *"Ошибка: переполнение стека целых чисел на строке 50" (for russian users)
>
> "Error: stack overflow of integers on line 50"*

I tried debug() and browse() to eliminate it but it didn't work. Maybe there is another way to get rid of the error. Or should I somehow incert the vector as a new column to the data so that median HH income values correspond with the column of states?

Comment: Please read the info at the top of the [tag:r] tag and in particular provide sample input using `dput` so that anyone, not just you, can run this.

Comment: I would recommend creating a data frame with two columns, state name and median household income. Then join this data frame to `data` using the `merge()` function if using base R, or `left_join()` if using tidyverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesting that goes extremely deep can cause problems. There are several alternatives - `merge()` or a join as suggested by qdread, `dplyr::case_when` if your conditions are more complicated, `switch()` can work too...

Assuming your `hincome` vector is in alphabetical order by state and you have all 50 US states, we can use the built-in `state.name` object to create a lookup table and then merge:

```
lookup_data = data.frame(hincome, State = state.name)
data = merge(data, lookup_data, by = "State", all.x = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I finally managed it with merge()